# How to store words in each line of a file to a list scala

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections

I am trying to read a file line by line and store all the words in each line to a list, then perform some computation on it.

I am doing the following:

```
for(line <- Source.fromFile("file1.txt").getLines())
 {
   var words_in_line = line.split("\\s+")
   println(words_in_line)
}
```

But, this prints something like:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@3535a92b
[Ljava.lang.String;@55f56157
```

What is this? Why isn't it printing words in each line in a list?

EDIT:

I'm doing this now:

```
val w2 = """([A-Za-z])+""".r
 for(line <- Source.fromFile("/Users/Martha/Desktop/file1.txt").getLines.flatMap(w2.findAllIn))
 {
   println("this is")
   println(line)

   var w1 = line.split("\\s+")
   //var w2 = w1.deep.mkString(" ")
   var w3 = line.split("\\s").toList
   println(w3)

 }
```

to get only the words and no digits or punctuations. But, it gives me only single words in the lists as output and not list of words in the line. Why is this so?

Answer (score 0):

```
var words_in_line = line.split("\\s+")

//words_in_line is an Array
```

you can't print `Array` by `println(words_in_line)`

try

```
scala> var line="hey hello this is demo"
line: String = hey hello this is demo

scala> var words=line.split("\\s+")
words: Array[String] = Array(hey, hello, this, is, demo)

scala> words map println
hey
hello
this
is
demo
res8: Array[Unit] = Array((), (), (), (), ())
```

you want   `List(hey, hello, this, is, demo)` like then

```
scala> var words=line.split("\\s+").toList
words: List[String] = List(hey, hello, this, is, demo)

scala> println(words)
List(hey, hello, this, is, demo)
```

Comment: But, this does not print it in the form of list of words! The first one prints it as words simply, and the second one makes it into one string. I want to print it as List(abc, vdc,...)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you help me at one more thing? Could you please read my EDIT in the question. I'm having trouble with that. :(

Answer (score 0):

When you do getLines and flatMap the result is a single list of individual words. If you need List of words in the line you need to separate those 2 calls:

```
for( line  <- io.Source.fromFile("all.txt").getLines ) {
   val words = w2.findAllIn(line)
   println("this is")
   println(words.mkString(" "))
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var w3 = line.split("\\s")
w3.foreach(m -> println(m))
```